# How to tell if element with certain class does not exist (PURE JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that creates a new paragraph element within a div and gives it the class "taskparagraph". I want to check if any elements with this class exist, and if not, add another (unrelated) paragraph.

I genuinely have no clue how to do something like this even though it seems like such a simple task. Maybe I'm just not Googling the right things...

P.S. I do not plan on using any JS libraries like jQuery for now. If using something like that is the only possible way to do this task please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
if (!document.querySelector('.taskparagraph')) { // or compare with null
    // no element with class "taskparagraph" exists
}
```